# Laravel: get details about a queue job

Tags: laravel, queue, laravel-artisan

How can I get job details from its ID, ex: `866FvqTxVVvi4PmCo7kHmD7u7bHaxCdn`

got that id from `queue:listen`, thanks[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't a built in way of doing this through Laravel. It entirely depends upon which queue driver you are using.

For example, if you are using Redis then you would need to use the Redis CLI to search through the database for the appropriate task.

Comment: So this id come from driver, not from laravel?

Comment: There will be a record in whatever driver you are using that has that ID. Laravel will generate that ID and store it within the store of whatever driver you are using, whether that is Redis, Beanstalk etc.

Comment: By the way, Laravel provides a nice interface to manage Redis queues : https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/horizon

Comment: @VincentDecaux correct, just a note that this **only** works for the Redis queue driver